# How to Pivot data from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data in following format:

[image]

I need to format it in a way that I get infor for each client in one row with address and start date and end date. Example:
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does your use of the word "format" imply that the data need to be arranged this way for presentation (i.e., outside of the database), or do you want to restructure the data like this in the database?  If the latter, why do you need it this way?  What problem are you trying to solve that can't be solved with data in a normalized form?

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is how it should be presented in output.

Comment: I tried pivoting it, but didn't work or I am not doing it correctly.

Comment: As I recall, SQL Server's PIVOT command only allows you to crosstab by one column but you are crosstabbing by groups of three columns.  I haven't done this in SQL Server in years, though--maybe newer versions are more capable.  An alternative is to export the normalized data and crosstab it outside the database.

Comment: images of data are so frustrating, why not just copy/paste as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE client_address
>     ([id] int, [clientid] int, [Address] varchar(3), [StartDate] date, [EndDate] datetime)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO client_address
>     ([id], [clientid], [Address], [StartDate], [EndDate])
> VALUES
>     (1, 123, 'sdf', '2015-03-17', '2015-12-23'),
>     (2, 123, 'pqr', '2015-12-23', '2016-10-23'),
>     (3, 123, 'abc', '2016-10-23', NULL)
> ;
>
> select
>   clientid
> , max(case when rn=3 then address end)   address1
> , max(case when rn=3 then StartDate end) StartDate1
> , max(case when rn=3 then EndDate end)   EndDate1
> , max(case when rn=2 then address end)   address2
> , max(case when rn=2 then StartDate end) StartDate2
> , max(case when rn=2 then EndDate end)   EndDate2
> , max(case when rn=1 then address end)   address3
> , max(case when rn=1 then StartDate end) StartDate3
> , max(case when rn=1 then EndDate end)   EndDate3
> from (
>      select
>      *
>      , row_number() over(partition by clientid order by coalesce(EndDate,getdate()) DESC) as rn
>      from client_address
>      ) ca
> where rn < 4
> group by
>   clientid
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> clientid | address1 | StartDate1          | EndDate1            | address2 | StartDate2          | EndDate2            | address3 | StartDate3          | EndDate3
> -------: | :------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------- | :------------------ | :-------
>      123 | sdf      | 17/03/2015 00:00:00 | 23/12/2015 00:00:00 | pqr      | 23/12/2015 00:00:00 | 23/10/2016 00:00:00 | abc      | 23/10/2016 00:00:00 | null    
>
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cf4d097e4ee0c8f6f727b6034a0c4d2f)*

Comment: thanks for your reply. The only problem is that for some records it's not 3 start and end dates values but might be more or even less (example just 1 start and end date or 4 values). is there any way by which we can dynamically get these records –

Comment: To get infinite variability you need more complex code. Known as "dynamic sql" its not impossible just harder.

Comment: But you really are advised to choose a maximum number if adresses you want to cater for in this wide de-normalized presentation.